# How to fetch images that stored in comma separated format in single row in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I am uploading multiple images in the database in a single column with comma separated format. I am first creating a folder for each user and inside that folder, images are stored. `car_images` is my root directory inside that with the name of `logged_in` user new directory will create.

My images are stored in below format :
[image]

Here, `emp_code` is unique I am using this as SESSION and for the name of the folder of each user. 
as you see `car_images` column where I am storing image name with `,`.
I am using below code to stored images in folders and database. I don't know idea how to fetch all images of a single user.

```
$car_images_all="";
        for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['car_images']['name']); $i++) 
        {
           $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['car_images']['tmp_name'][$i];    
           if ($tmpFilePath != "")
            {    
                if (!file_exists('car_images/'.$emp_code)) 
                    {
                        mkdir('car_images/'.$emp_code, 0777, true);
                    }
                $location = 'car_images/'.$emp_code.'/';
               $name = $_FILES['car_images']['name'][$i];
               $size = $_FILES['car_images']['size'][$i];

               list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
               $file= time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 0);
               $info = pathinfo($file);
               $filename = $file.".".$ext;
               if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['car_images']['tmp_name'][$i], $location.$filename)) 
               { 
                  $car_images_all.=$filename.",";
               }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use `explode`. See this. http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: what is your table name?

Comment: Have you not stored user id in your emp tables?

Comment: Moving forward, normalise your schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php 
 $x=0;                                                
 $car_img =explode(",",$car_images);
 foreach($car_img as $car_images{                                                  
 $x+=1;0
 ?>                                                 
 <?php   echo '<img src="'."images/".$car_images.'" width="70" height="70" />';?>
```

Comment: Please try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all,
Select all images from database by emp_code (as you want all images of a particular user/emp).

```
select car_images from TableName where emp_code = $emp_code;
```

Now, by this you will get one or more rows.
So, add one by one images to array with using explode() function per row (i.e. if row has multiple image name with comma separated).
Use the array as per your choice of manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

Below code will fetch the data from table and save images in array. For more details check the explode function.

```
$query = "select car_images from table_name where emp_code = 'emp_code'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$images = $row['car_images'];
$images = explode(',',$images);
foreach($images AS $image){
    echo '<img src="car_images/'.$emp_code.'/'.$image.'">';
}
```

Comment: `echo '<img src="car_images/'.$emp_code.'/'.$images.'">';` on this code it shows me error of array to string conversion

Comment: on print_r it shows me this array `Array ( [0] => 152568159906102016_used_car_sale-1.jpg [1] => 1525681599Mechanic_Using_Wrench_And_Socket_Under_Car_Hood.jpg ) Array ( [0] => 1525681893WIN_20170511_10_29_34_Pro.jpg [1] => 1525681893WIN_20170511_10_29_36_Pro.jpg )`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` function

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(car_images) FROM TableName
```

You can use group by also with emp_code or brand_id or any other column whatever your business logic is met.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(car_images) FROM TableName GROUP BY emp_code
```

OR

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(car_images) FROM TableName GROUP BY brand_id
```